# 3rd Party Library with Angular 2, D3 and Vizuly

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, ecmascript-6, webpack

I would like to work with D3 and Vizuly to create their radial progress bar. However I'm struggling figuring out the Angular way to get these javascript files imported into my component. Can y'all help me figure out a way to get this to work? Thanks!

```
declare const d3:any;
declare const vizuly:any;
import '../../../assets/d3.min.js';
import '../../../assets/vizuly_core.min.js';
// I am getting a vizuly not defined error in the file below.
import '../../../assets/vizuly_radialprogress.min.js';

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'circlechart',
  template: `
  <div class="container">
    <div id="viz_container">
      <div id="chart_container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./circlechart.scss']
})
export class CircleChartComponent {
  constructor() {

    let viz_container;
    let chart_container;
    let viz;

    viz_container = d3.selectAll("#viz_container")
      .style("width", "600px")
      .style("height","600px");

    chart_container = d3.select('#chart_container');

    viz = vizuly.viz.radial_progress(document.getElementById('chart_container'));

    viz.data(80)
            .min(0)
            .max(100)
            .capRadius(1);

    viz.startAngle(250)        // Angle where progress bar starts
       .endAngle(110)          // Angle where the progress bar stops
       .arcThickness(.12)      // The thickness of the arc (as a ratio of radius)
       .label(function (d,i) { // The 'label' property allows us to use a dynamic function for labeling.
          return d3.format(".0f")(d);
        });

  }
}
```

Comment: If you remove your imports in the component and just import them in your index.html `<head>` does it work? I expect it to work but give type errors

Comment: no type errors, but it doesn't work because the scope within the component is still wrong. I don't think the component gets a global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plunker for demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CbVQhNl5nIuv4pl9j6HL?p=preview)

```
 d3.select("div")
      .transition().duration(500).style("width","500px")
      .transition().duration(500).style("height","500px")
      .transition().duration(500).style("color","red")
      .transition().duration(500).style("background-color","red");
```

As you can see I didn't import d3 inside the component and it works.
But if you try to do it in your IDE you will get type errors like "unknown property/module d3". That is because you are writing the code in typescript and typescript does not have a d3 module.

So you will need to get the 
[definition file for d3.js](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts)
and include it in your typings. Now typescript will know about this module and won't complain.

Comment: I can get d3 to work! They have their own modules for webpack also. It's Vizuly that is the issue.

Comment: @jaruesink It is basicly the same thing really.. Check the plunker, i've updated it for vizuly

Comment: I got it to work, I think I had the wrong viz object. I wasn't using .component. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For d3 library, someone has already made Angular2 component based on d3 library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-nvd3